Equivalent definitions of tensor power of a vector space
I have two definitions of the tensor power $T^nV$ of a vector space $V\in \bf{kVect}$.

For every $n$-multilinear map $f:V\times ...\times V\rightarrow W$, there exists a unique $\bar{f}:T^nV\rightarrow W$ such that $f(v_1,...,v_n) = \bar{f}(v_1\otimes ...\otimes v_n)$.

$T^nV = U_n(T(V))$ where $U_n:\textbf{kAlg}_{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \bf{kVect}$ is the forgetful functor which picks out the degree $n$ part of an $\mathbb{N}$-graded k-algebra.


I am failing to see cleanly why these define the same functor.
My thoughts on this so far are that the universal property (1.) of $V^{\otimes n}$ says that $\text{n-MultiLin}(V^{\times n}, W)\cong \text{Hom}_k(T^nV,W)$ are isomorphic as sets, and this isomorphism is natural in $V$ and $W$. So I believe I have a functor $F:\textbf{kVect}^{op}\times \textbf{kVect}\rightarrow \textbf{Set}$, and it is representable in the first variable by the object $T^nV$.
So. guess if I can show $\text{Hom}_k(U_nT(\bullet), W)\cong \text{Hom}_k({\bullet} ^{\otimes n}, W)$ I'd be done. But I'm getting a bit tripped up by all that's going on and the fact that $T^n$ isn't an adjoint or anything like that.
Also it's very easy to show that $T^1(V)\cong V$ because I can show $T$ is fully faithful and hence $\eta_V:V\rightarrow U_1T(V)$ is a natural isomorphism. But I don't see how this generalizes to show $V^{\otimes n}\cong U_nT(V)$.

What's your definition of $T(V)$?

@BenSteffan I'm defining T as the left adjoint to $U_1:\bf{kAlg}_{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \bf{kVect}$ "taking the degree 1 vector space of a graded k-algebra"

You could show that the left adjoint to $U_1$ is given by the explicit construction given e.g. here.

Indeed, that is basically my question: why are those the same?

It's not quite the same: You're looking at the problem level-wise; I'm suggesting you take it as a whole. Showing this explicit construction is left-adjoint to $U_1$ means showing the universal property in the Wikipedia article I linked, and you do this simply by constructing a map making the diagram commute. I suggest you either try this yourself or find a reference (here's one I found by a quick google search, for instance).
